# How to convert XML data to gridview

Tags: c#, xml, api, gridview

I am creating a Web site which retrieves data from the expedia site. The data comes in the XML format. Could you please let me know the best method to display them in a gridview?

XML response can be found in http://ean.mashery.com/docs/read/hotels/version_3/request_hotel_list/examples/XML_Basic_Availability

I see lot of example on how to convert the xml file into dataset but not able to find the samples to setup the gridview using the XML response (not an.xml file)

Comment: If you can get the data into a dataset, then simply set the `.DataSource` property of the gridview to that dataset. Depending on how much configuration you need to perform with the gridview, this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `XmlDataSource` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's an XmlDocument.

It's a DataSet.

It's both!  The XmlDataDocument:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx

[Edit]  I saw that class has recently become obsolete.  You can still use a DataSet or DataTable.  They have WriteXml() and ReadXml() methods.